# Advance search multistring in a SharePoint online list

Tags: sharepoint-online, list, search-results, choice-field

## Summary

I would like to know if it is possible to input a collection of strings to search in a list. The search should be use by normal users.

## Scenario

I have a SharePoint list called AnimalList.
In the list, there is a column "Animal". The column is a choice (Cat,Dog,Giraffe,...)
that allow multiple selection.

## Desire

If The user puts in input "dog,cat" I would like to get all the rows in the list that have the column Animal containing the value "dog" or containing the value "cat"

## What I tried

1. I try to use the "Search this list" box on top of the list but it
   does not work pretty well. Sometimes you put in input "string1" and
   you do not get all the rows that have Animal="string1" as one of the
   choice. Moreover I do not think you can put more than one search term.
2. I try to use the [PnP Modern Search
   v4](https://microsoft-search.github.io/pnp-modern-search/). This
   will require to create a custom version of the webpart. A good
   approach but a bit too custom.

I would like to know if there is an out of the box solution or an app in the SharePoint store that has this functionality.

Any idea is welcome!
Thanks in advance,
Alessandro

Answer (score 0):

To search for multiple keywords, you can use `OR/AND` to return all the rows containing the keywords you're searching for.

[Using Operators in Keyword Queries](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/sharepoint-2010/ee872310(v=office.14))

In your example, the search query "Dog OR Cat" should return the desired result.

Comment: This is working fine for a little list with a few choice. When I scale this to a bigger list (7 columns, a column choice with 1000+ elements, 300 rows) the search is not giving back the correct info. FYI I am using with SharePoint Online.

Comment: Yes, your scenario described were small. As there is other options using the KQL, your users would need to learn how to search. What's missing in the PnP Search webparts that would need to be modified to suit your requirements? Won't the OOTB list filters work for you?

Comment: PnP Search webparts is very good, but I cannot filter on multiple string. It is good for "Cat" but not for "Cat or Dog"